# jQuery append() string concatenation in id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is a string I want to add in a `div`'s `id`.

```
var str = "abcs's ah js";
$("div").append("<div id=" + str + ">JKL</div>");
```

When it renders it looks like this:

```
<div id="abc" ah="" js="" s></div>
```

Comment: Missing quotes, try 
`$("div").append('<div id="' + str + '">JKL</div>');`

Comment: @BrianHannay The `'` in his string would cause trouble with quoting id with single quotes. Not that I know if `'` is valid in an id anyway :)

Comment: @downvoter should care to explain , so in future i will keep that things in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str` has `'` quote, it is not valid value for `id` attribute, till HTML5 .. it is (`'`) valid in HTML 5.

**please note space in  in `str`. which is also not valid in html5 and html4.**

[HTML5 id attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute)

for adding your `str` value to id attribute.  try below code

```
 $("div").append('<div id="' + str + '">JKL</div>');
```

you can select them using attribute selector  eg : `$('[id="'+str+'"]')[0]`.  I have added it in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hYNxZ/) .

@jack thanks for comment

Comment: Thanks i tried this already but in-vane

Comment: @user2413182 I tried it in http://jsfiddle.net/hYNxZ/ .. it works

Comment: Spaces are still not valid in HTML5.

Comment: @Jack I explain about `'` quote. `your id has ' quote, it is not valid value for id attribute, till HTML5` . and given link to html 5 id attribute specification .. here user can read about space ..

Comment: @Jack updated answer with `it is (') valid in HTML 5.`

Answer (score 4):

In general you can let jQuery take care of attribute escaping in this way:

```
var str = "abcs's ah js",
$newdiv = $('<div>', {id: str});

$("div").append($newdiv);
```

Do note that, even though this might work, according to the standards of [HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.2) and [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html-markup-20101019/datatypes.html#common.data.id-def) regarding valid identifier names, the use of spaces is forbidden and single quotes (amongst others) won't work in HTML4.

Answer (score 4):

An ID with quotes and spaces in it [is not valid](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Remove invalid characters and it will work.

UPDATE (thanks to @Joachim Isaksson): In [HTML5 quotes are allowed for ID attribute](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class), in this case you can refer to [@Jack's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16767446/1338292) and let jQuery handle attribute escaping.

Comment: In [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-id-attribute) quotes seem to be valid, although spaces still are not.

Answer (score -2):

You can do that by using the above answers but space character is not a valid for ID attribute.